# Conditonal expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation

Consider two dependent random variables $X$ and $Y$, i.e. $E(X|Y) = g(Y)$, where $g$ is the conditional mean function.
From the conditionning theorem we know that $E(X|X)=X$.
Can we similarly simplify the expression $E(X|X,Y)$ in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $E[X|X, Y] = X$, which is a direct application of the "pulling out known factors out" (the fifth item in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties)) property of conditional expectation.

In general, formally, suppose $X$ is defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ and $\mathscr{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathscr{F}$, then if $X$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable, then $E[X|\mathscr{G}] = X$. Heuristically, $X$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable means that for any real value $x$, we know whether the event $\{\omega: X(\omega) = x\}$ occurs or not.  Consequently, given the "partial information" of $\mathscr{G}$, $X$ is completely determined, whence $E[X|\mathscr{G}] = X$.

Also note that "$E[X|X, Y]$" is a shorthand for $E[X|\mathscr{G}]$ with $\mathscr{G} = \sigma(X, Y)$, which by definition is the smallest $\sigma$-field in $\mathscr{F}$ with respect to which $(X, Y)$ is measurable. If $(X, Y)$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable, certainly $X$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable (in other words, $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(X, Y)$ always holds).